# distance jQuery UI draggable object has been moved, dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using the following code to allow for all members of the `.dataCard` class to be draggable left or right, but revert back to their original positions.

`$('.dataCard').draggable({ axis: 'x', revert: true });`

How can I tell the distance the item is away from its original position?

Comment: What are exactly trying to do??

Comment: @user1145009 Fire an alert if it has been moved / dragged a certain distance away from its starting point in either direction ( left or right )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have made it across one axis only ..

```
drag: function (e, ui){
            y2 = ui.position.top;
            x2 = ui.position.left;
            if(y2>100){alert("greater");}
                    if(y2>100){alert("greater");}

        }
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/sAX4W/36/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `left` CSS property to determine how far it moved on the `revert` event:

```
revert: function() {
    alert($(this).css('left'));
    return true;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uFrC5/1/)

Comment: The difference is jst that u r alerting on revert function ..and me on drag only with some simple if conditions..PArtially ur right .. upvote for u

Answer (score 0):

The actual math is trigonometry, and you need to calculate the distance, even if diagonal.

On start:

```
start_position = ui.position;
```

then on drag: which occurs in every mouse move, you calculate the distance like

```
if ( lineDistance( start_position , ui.position ) > 100 ) 
  {
    //do something here
  }
```

The function that does the magic is this:

```
function lineDistance( point1, point2)
{
  var xs = 0;
  var ys = 0;

  xs = point2.x - point1.x;
  xs = xs * xs;

  ys = point2.y - point1.y;
  ys = ys * ys;

  return Math.sqrt( xs + ys );
}
```